# Subtract 2 dates from different textbox and auto populate age in 3rd textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

[How to populate age automatically after i enter Date of birh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euvmk.png)

I want to subtract 2 dates from different textbox and auto populate age in 3rd textbox

Textbox7 has TODAY'S DATE

Textbox3 has Date of Birth

in textbox4 i want to auto populate AGE only in (years).

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Sherry

Comment: Please, try `Format(Me.TextBox3.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")` and it will correctly format any date. Can you explain why did you try that way? What real format do you need to be returned/displayed? The age can be calculated using `DateDiff`. Please, try  `Debug.print DateDiff("yyyy", CDate(TextBox3.Value), Date, vbMonday)`.

Comment: If you enter 15 is that 1915 or 2015 ? You have to decide a breakpoint between 0 99 where the year changes century.

Comment: Check the length `If Len(Me.TextBox3.Value)=3 Then`

Comment: @CDP1802 can you create a vba code like you created before in my 1st post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use If/ElseIf code blocks for each of the valid entry formats and add the century as appropriate.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()

    Dim s As String, dob As Date
    Dim age As Long, bday As Date
    
    s = TextBox3.Text 'dob
    TextBox4 = "" ' age
    If Len(s) = 0 Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If IsNumeric(s) Then
        If s Like "##" Then
            dob = DateSerial("19" & s, 1, 1)
        ElseIf TextBox3 Like "0##" Then
            dob = DateSerial("2" & s, 1, 1)
        ElseIf TextBox3 Like "####" Then
            dob = DateSerial(s, 1, 1)
        Else
            TextBox3 = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf s Like "*#/*#/*##" And IsDate(s) Then
        dob = DateValue(s)
    Else
        TextBox3 = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' calc age if valid dob
    If IsDate(dob) Then
        If dob > Date Then
            MsgBox "Birthday in future ?"
        Else
            TextBox3 = Format(dob, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            
            '  had birthday this year ?
            bday = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(dob), Day(dob))
            age = Year(Date) - Year(dob)
            If Date < bday Then age = age - 1
            
            TextBox4 = age
        End If
    Else
        TextBox3 = ""
    End If
    
End Sub
```